# Seeking the minimum without calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Imagine booking a ticket to the first octant of $\,\mathbb R^3$ and landing 
 on the surface given by $$xyz\:=\:x+y+z+2\,.\tag{S}$$
This defining  constraint for $\,x,y,z\geqslant0\,$ is equivalent to
$$\frac 1{x+1}+\frac1{y+1}+\frac1{z+1}\:=\:1$$
which reminds a bit of conjugate exponents in two dimensions (that is
$\frac 1p+\frac 1q=1$).

My pair of questions (the second of which depends on the first one):

- Does either side of (S), say $h:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R, (x,y,z)\mapsto xyz$, when restricted to the surface, has a unique absolute minimum in $(2,2,2)$?
- May this be proved along an "algebraic track", that is *without* using Lagrange multipliers?

I came across (S) during the analysis of this [inequality question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698147/316749) on this SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [AM-HM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality):

$$
3 = \frac{3}{\cfrac 1{x+1}+\cfrac1{y+1}+\cfrac1{z+1}} \le \frac{x+1+y+1+z+1}{3} = 1 + \frac{x+y+z}{3} = 1 + \frac{xyz - 2}{3}
$$

Therefore $\,xyz \ge 8\,$ with equality iff $\,x=y=z=2\,$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the AM-GM inequality instead of Lagrange multipliers. Let $a^3 = xyz$. Then we have that

$$
  a^3 = xyz = x + y + z + 2 \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{xyz} + 2 = 3a + 2.
$$
Equality occurs if and only if $x = y = z$.

We thus have that
$$
  a^3 - 3a - 2 \geq 0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
  (a + 1)^2 (a - 2) \geq 0
$$
and so $a \geq 2$.

We thus have that $xyz \geq 2^3 = 8$, and for equality to occur, we must have that $x = y = z = 2$.

Comment: @dxiv
Both answers by Dylan and dxiv are GREAT & settle the OP by 100% (+1+1). I'm going to accept dxiv's proposal: It's even more appealing in its slimness to me, by exploiting both forms of the constraint equation.